# How to put definition of a funtion on the same line as text?

Tags: align

I want to write the definition on a function on the same line in the paragraph as the rest of the text, since for the definition I need two lines aligned, the align* environment creates a problem.
Basically what I want is "...this function *{FUNCTION}* does this..." without breaking the paragraph in two.

The definition of the function is somewhat like this

```
\begin{align*}
  f\colon[0,\infty)&\longrightarrow[0,1)\\
  z&\mapsto\frac{z}{1+z}\\
\end{align*}
```

Comment: The aligned environment can be used in inline math: `\( \begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned} \)`, but I don't really understand what you're trying to do. You wrote that you need two lines aligned, but you're using `\phantom{++++}` so that nothing on the bottom line is actually lined up with the top line, which defeats the purpose, doesn't it? What is supposed to be aligned with what?

Comment: Thanks this did it. the ```\phantom{++++}``` was just part of a code I copied from some other site, I will update the post with the actual code I used

Comment: Do you want something like this? `$f\colon[0,\infty)\to[0,1),\ z\mapsto\frac{z}{1+z}$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As frabjous mentioned, to use the environment inline is has to be done with `\( \begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned} \)`. So the example on the question would be like

```
...this function $\quad$
\( \begin{aligned}
f\colon[0,\infty)&\longrightarrow[0,1)\\
                z&\mapsto\frac{z}{1+z}\\
\end{aligned} \) $\quad$
does this...
```

[image]